Schwartz function realized as the divergence of a schwarz vector field has null integral
I am learning some fourier analysis on my own and I encountered the following problem for which I would greatly appreciate if anyone could guide me through my attempt.
Assume that $\psi$ is a Schwartz function such that $\psi=\nabla_i v^i$ for some schwartz vector field $v$, i.e. each factor $v^i$ is a schwartz function. Then $\int \psi=0$.
**My attempt for a proof **
Apply the fourier transform to both sides to get $$\hat{\psi}(\xi) =\sum_{j=1}^{n}\hat{\frac{\partial}{\partial x_{i}}v^{j}}(\xi)\\
  =\sum_{j=1}^{n}i\xi_{j}\hat{v}^{j}(\xi) $$
Recall that (maybe as a tempered distribution) $\delta_{0}(\xi)=\int e^{-i\xi x}dx$, maybe up to a constant, and $\delta_0$ is the dirac delta function. So, we compute $$ \begin{align*}\int\psi dx & =\int\Big(\int e^{-i\xi x}\hat{\psi}(\xi)d\xi\Big)dx\\
 & =\int\Big(\int e^{-i\xi x}\sum_{j=1}^{n}i\xi_{j}\hat{v}^{j}(\xi)d\xi\Big)dx\\
 & =i\sum_{j=1}^{n}\int\int e^{-i\xi x}\xi_{j}\hat{v}^{j}(\xi)d\xi dx\\
\text{Apply Fubini because }e^{-i\xi x}\xi_{j}\hat{v}^{j}(\xi) & =i\sum_{j=1}^{n}\int\int e^{-i\xi x}\xi_{j}\hat{v}^{j}(\xi)dxd\xi\\
\text{is schwartz and, thus, }L^{1} & =i\sum_{j=1}^{n}\int\xi_{j}\hat{v}^{j}(\xi)\int e^{-i\xi x}dxd\xi\\
\text{Letting }\phi_{j}(\xi)=\xi_{j}\hat{v}^{j}(\xi) & =i\sum_{j=1}^{n}\int\phi_{j}(\xi)\delta_{0}(\xi)d\xi\\
 & =i\sum_{j=1}^{n}\phi_{j}(0)=0 \end{align*}$$
This is the proof I have in mind, and I would greatly appreciate if you could give me some feedback about it. I am new in Fourier analysis and I want to make sure that I am not having a big misunderstanding. Thanks in advance.

Why not just use the divergence theorem?  $\int_{\Omega} \nabla v = \oint_{\partial \Omega} v\hat n$, where $\hat n$ is the outward unit normal to $\partial \Omega$.
